# Creating a Auto Updating <div></div> When Information Was Pasted on Mysql

Tags: php, html, posts

It's my first day here, I thought you guys could help me. So, I'm working on this kind of chatting service for a friend. I want it to auto update anything inside the div tags that has an id of messages. I tried adding some javascript and stuff from other posts, but they just made it worse. So, if anyone could fix it and comment, or give me suggestions. I want it as soon as someone posted something, it updates the posts in the div tags with the id of messages.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{

header("Location: /index.php");

}

?>
<html>

<head>

<title>
House Email System
</title>

<style>

body
{
background: #383838;
font-family: Arial;
color: #444444;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -75px;
margin-left: -150px;
}

form
{
background: #ffffff;
width: 270px;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #303030;
}

input
{
margin-left: 15px;
}

p
{
margin-left: 15px;
}

error
{
padding:2px 4px;
margin:0px;
border:solid 1px #FBD3C6;
background:#FDE4E1;
color:#CB4721;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
}

div
{
background: #f0f0f0;
}

hr
{
color: #d0d0d0;
background-color: #d0d0d0;
height: 3px;
border: 0px;
}

username
{
margin-left: 5px;
}

message
{
margin-left: 10px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*******");
mysql_select_db("*******");

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if($submit)
{

if($message)
{

mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('', '$username', '$message')");

}
else
{

?>

<center>

<error>Please enter a message to send.</error> <br />

</center>

<br />

<?php

}

}

?>

<form action="active.php" method="POST">

<br />

<p>Message</p>
<input type="text" name="message" /> <br />

<br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> <br />

<br />

<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num_rows > 0)
{

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$username = $row['username'];
$message = $row['message'];

?>

<div id="messages">

<br /> <username><b><?php echo $username; ?></b></username>

<hr />

<message><?php echo $message; ?></message> <br />

<br /> </div> <br />

<?php

}

}
else
{

?>

<center>

<error>There are no messages to display.</error> <br />

</center>

<br />

<?php

}

?>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope you guys can help me, thank you.

Comment: there must better solutions from building something like that from scratch , try googling "ajax chat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a page message.php as:

```
        <?php
session_start();
?>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#submit').click(function()
            {
            //alert("hello");
           // ss=document.getElementById("message").value;

                $.ajax({
                      type : 'POST',
                      url : 'active.php',

                     data: {
                     messages :$('#message').val()
                       },
                      success : function(data){

                         $('#messages').html(data);
}

                });


            });
        });
    </script>

<title>
House Email System
</title>

<style>

body
{
background: #383838;
font-family: Arial;
color: #444444;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -75px;
margin-left: -150px;
}

form
{
background: #ffffff;
width: 270px;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 1px #303030;
}

input
{
margin-left: 15px;
}

p
{
margin-left: 15px;
}

error
{
padding:2px 4px;
margin:0px;
border:solid 1px #FBD3C6;
background:#FDE4E1;
color:#CB4721;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
}

div
{
background: #f0f0f0;
}

hr
{
color: #d0d0d0;
background-color: #d0d0d0;
height: 3px;
border: 0px;
}

username
{
margin-left: 5px;
}

message
{
margin-left: 10px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>



<center>

<error>Please enter a message to send.</error> <br />

</center>

<br />



<form action="active.php" method="POST">

<br />

<p>Message</p>
<input type="text" name="message" id="message" /> <br />

<br />

<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> <br />
</form>
<br />

<div id="messages">



</div>

</body>

</html>



<script language="JavaScript"><!--
// v3 compatible:
function doSomething() {
   // do something here...
   $.ajax({
                      type : 'POST',
                      url : 'active.php',

                     data: {
                     messages :$('#message').val()
                       },
                      success : function(data){

                         $('#messages').html(data);
}

                });
   setTimeout('doSomething()',3000);
}
setInterval('doSomething()',3000);
//--></script>
```

Then Create a page active.php as

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("test");

$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$message=$_POST['messages'];

if($message!="")
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('', '$username', '$message')");
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC limit 1,0");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num_rows > 0)
{

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$username = $row['username'];
$message = $row['message'];

?>

<div>

<br /> <username><b><?php echo $username; ?></b></username>

<hr />

<message><?php echo $message; ?></message> <br />

<br /> </div>


<br />

<?php

}

}
else
{

echo"No message to show";
}
?>
```

**This is very general chat.Now you need to change it according to your requirements.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this just not working. When you go to active.php it posts random posts, then when you go to message.php you'll have to post something to see the other posts. If you are in, it doesn't update when someone else writes.

Comment: I have made little changes as per your above requirements.Please do not go to page directly on active.php

Comment: Now it works, but instead of creating 1 message and posting it, it posts a ton. Also, it messes up the CSS at the end of the form.

Comment: Please check the updated one for the above mentioned point.Just putted limit in query....

Answer (score 0):

```
I want it as soon as someone posted something, it updates the posts in the div tags with the id of messages.
```

You will have to use javacript for that part. Everything else can be done with PHP and MySQL.

I watched great youtube tutorial the other day on how to do this. Its is a "quick and dirty" solution but should give you something to build on. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyXeOX-uYMc

Comment: I'm not good with javascript, but the last time I tried adding it, it did update the messages, but it also repeats the form. Can you at least add it to the script and send it to me?